# Possible to use C11 fences to reason about writes from other threads?

Tags: c, c11, memory-model, memory-barriers, memory-fences

[Adve and Gharachorloo's report](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/WRL-95-7.pdf), in Figure 4b, provides the following example of a program that exhibits unexpected behavior in the absence of sequential consistency:

[image]

My question is whether it is possible, using only C11 fences and `memory_order_relaxed` loads and stores, to ensure that register1, if written, will be written with the value 1.  The reason this might be hard to guarantee in the abstract is that P1, P2, and P3 could be at different points in a pathological NUMA network with the property that P2 sees P1's write before P3 does, yet somehow P3 sees P2's write very quickly.  The reason this might be hard to guarantee with respect to the C11 spec specifically is that P1's write to A and P2's read of A do not synchronize with each other, and therefore by paragraph 5.1.2.4.26 of the spec will result in undefined behavior.  Possibly I can sidestep the undefined behavior through relaxed atomic fetch/store, but I still don't know how to reason transitively about the order seen by P3.

Below is a MWE attempting to solve the problem with fences, but I'm not sure if it is correct.  I'm specifically worried that the release fence is not good enough, because it won't flush p1's store buffer, just p2's.  However, it will answer my question if you can argue the assert will never fail just based on the C11 standard (as opposed to some other information one might have about a particular compiler and architecture).

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <threads.h>

atomic_int a = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);
atomic_int b = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);

void
p1(void *_ignored)
{
  atomic_store_explicit(&a, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
}

void
p2(void *_ignored)
{
  if (atomic_load_explicit(&a, memory_order_relaxed)) {
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release); // not good enough?
    atomic_store_explicit(&b, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
  }
}

void
p3(void *_ignored)
{
  int register1 = 1;
  if (atomic_load_explicit(&b, memory_order_relaxed)) {
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
    register1 = atomic_load_explicit(&a, memory_order_relaxed);
  }
  assert(register1 != 0);
}

int
main()
{
  thrd_t t1, t2, t2;
  thrd_create(&t1, p1, NULL);
  thrd_create(&t2, p2, NULL);
  thrd_create(&t3, p3, NULL);
  thrd_join(&t1, NULL);
  thrd_join(&t2, NULL);
  thrd_join(&t3, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget `memory_order_acquire` fence in `p3`:

```
void
p3(void *_ignored)
{
  int register1 = 1;
  if (atomic_load_explicit(&b, memory_order_relaxed)) {
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire); // <-- Here
    register1 = atomic_load_explicit(&a, memory_order_relaxed);
  }
  assert(register1 != 0);
}
```

With this fence, loading `a` in `p2` will be in *happens-before* relation with loading `a` in `p3`.

C11 standard garantees *read-read* coherence, which means that the loading in `p3` should observe **same-or-subsequent modification**, which is observed by the *happened-before* loading in `p2`. Because the loading in `p2` observes the store in `p1`, and no *subsequent* modifications of `a` is possible in your scenario, loading in `p3` should also observe storing in `p1`.

So your assertion can never trigger.

---

**References to the corresponded statements in the standard**:

> 5.1.2.4 p.25: The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is **not atomic**, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

So, *atomic* accesses cannot contain data race by definition.

> 5.1.2.4 p.22: ... if a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, and the value computed by A corresponds to the value stored by side effect X, then the value computed by B shall **either equal the value computed by A, or be the value stored by side effect Y, where Y follows X in the modification order of M.**

Next paragraph says, that this is *cache coherence garantee*. C++11 standard is more specific, and says about *read-read cache coherence* in similar wording.

Comment: Thanks for the missing fence.  Can you make your argument based on the C11 standard text?  At a minimum, this requires showing a) that two conflicting `memory_order_relaxed` operations do not create a data race (and hence undefined behavior), and b) that, as you say, the C11 spec guarantees read-read coherence.

Comment: I have updated my answer with references to the standard.

Comment: Thanks for the references.  Unfortunately, I still cannot connect your second quote to my question.  Does M correspond to b here, while A and X both correspond to p2's write of b and B corresponds to p3's read of b?  Then somehow for the language to be relevant you need to argue that A happens before B.  Seems intuitive given that B observed A's side effect, but A would have to inter-thread happen before B.  How do you argue that?  Does A synchronize with B (and if so by what argument)?  Or is it the accesses to a that synchronize with respect to each other?

Comment: No, *read-read coherence*, described by the second quote, is related to accesses to `a` (as *M*): *A* is reading in `p2`, *B* is reading in `p3`, *X* is writting in `p1`. *A* sees effect of *X* (otherwise *B* won't occure). So *B* also sees effect of *X*. Happens-before order between *A* and *B* is classic and is provided by accesses to `b` and fences. If you failed to catch reason of that happens-before, you better ask new question: it is fundamental one, and I'm sure it will collect many views(and upvotes).

Comment: No I understand classical happens before; my problem is happens before has a very specific definition in the C11 spec and I can't convince myself it matches classical happens before.  But I think maybe I understand my confusion.  To me, because of the definite article, "the value stored by side effect X" reads like it must be the value stored in object M computed by A, otherwise I would expect to read "a value stored by side effect X."  Is your interpretation that X can be any side effect storing any value, not just M?

Comment: No, *X* is stroring value into `a`(*M*) by `p1`. So your interpretation is correct. Probably you confused, that given read-read coherence is unrelated to arguing of happens-before relation between A* and *B*? It *uses* this relation.

Comment: I appreciate your patience, but I still don't see how it maps to my example.  First, coherence only really says anything about a single memory location (really, cache line).  The issue here is about multiple memory locations that might propagate at different speeds in a NUMA machine.  Second, the quoted language "if a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before a value computation B" only applies if A _happens before_ B.  And in the peculiar definition of that term given by 5.1.2.3.18, I don't think any computation happens before any other in my example.

Comment: *Happens-before* term is **universal**; after being proved it isn't binded to particular memory location. So, after proving *happens-before*  relation between *A* and *B* by using accesses to variable `b`, this fact can be used in *cache coherence* for variable `a`.

Comment: I don't think you can claim happens-before is universal in light of 5.1.2.4.18 which actually defines the term.  Moreover, by way of example, C++N3290 in 1.10.6 notes says: "This states that the modification orders must respect the `happens before' relationship... There is a separate order for each atomic object. There is no requirement that these can be combined into a single total order for all objects."  So that's at least one language with a very non-Lamport notion of happens before.  My question is about the perceived order of a=1 vs. b=1, not about two writes to the same location.

Comment: *happens-before* relation is universal in sence that it doesn't binded to a particular location. Phrase `There is a separate order for each atomic object.` doesn't deny the requirement, that for *any* atomic variable `modification order must respect the happens-before relationship`. Your question is about concrete assertion garantee, term *preceived order* isn`t strictly defined by the standard.

Comment: But the assertion in my code can fail without violating happens before for any atomic object.  All three threads agree that a=1 happened after a=0 (initialization), and that b=1 happened after b=0.  Without violating the per-variable global modification ordered implied by coherence, it is possible for p2 to see a=1 before p3 does.  Since p1's write does not "inter-thread happen before" any other operation in the whole program, I don't know how C11 guarantees that p3 will see it by any particular point.  You could fix it by having p2 rewrite a=1 before the fence, but that's not my question.

Comment: `per-variable global modification ordered implied by coherence` - cache coherence is not involved into global modification order garantee. Cache coherence implies, that whenever `p1` write has "inter-thread happens-before" or not, **if this write is perceived by the reading** (in `p2`), and **this reading is in happens-before relation with other reading** (in `p3`), then the **other reading will perceive this write**. Any NUMA machine has mechanisms for provide that garantee, and compiler is required to use this mechanism.

Comment: I took your advice and asked a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244647/what-does-happens-before-mean-in-the-c11-spec) about happens-before, albeit in the context of C++.  At least for C++, the comments suggested that "if" should be read as "if an only if" in the definition of happens before.  If we apply the same logic to C11 5.1.2.4/18, then the store in `p1` does not happen before any other evaluation in `p2` or `p3`, because it does not inter-thread happen before any other evaluation.  So that means the assertion can fail after all.

Comment: You incorrectly read statement about cache coherence. It **doesn't imply that write in `p1` is in *happens-before* order with read in `p3`**. It just say that read in `p3` will get what is written by `p1`. Nothing more above that. E.g., if you have another write in `p1` before given one, this write isn't garanteed to be seen by `p3`.

Comment: But the language you quote in 5.1.2.5/22 is prefixed with "if a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M."  So unless A happens before B, I don't see how that text is relevant.

Comment: `A` is read in `p2`, `B` is read in `p3`. In one of your previous comment you said you understand that they are in happens-before relation (deduced from `b` variable's accesses and fences).